# Create an observer to do action every time interval in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

Using RxJava, is it possible to create an observer to do some action with an interval of n seconds?

I would like to create an observable from the console input stream, and in the observer, I would want to do some action on the value with an interval of n seconds. Something like:

```
StringObservable.from(System.in)
            .subscribe(input -> {
                // 1. read the input value and store it once the value is 
                // received
                //
                // 2. for every n seconds, do some action  
            });
```

I have tried using the while true loop, but that would block the rest of the program forever.

```
StringObservable.from(System.in)
                .subscribe(input -> {
                    // 1. read the input value and store it once the 
                    //value is received
                    //
                    while (true) {
                      try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                    
                      // do some action
                    } 
                });
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of what you want to do. If possible provide some kind of diagram which shows what should happen at what time when you read data from the console input stream. Provide the example input value as well.

Comment: Do you only want to accept a single string, via `System.in`, or do you want to accept a new string every few seconds?

Comment: To accept a new string whenever there is input from the console, and then to do some processing (every few seconds) based on the input. I'm thinking of if this can be done using RxJava, rather than like using a while loop to read the console value into bufferedreader or scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Try `combineLatest` with `interval`:

```java
Observable.combineLatest(
    StringObservable.from(System.in),
    Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
    (input, time) -> String.format("%d - %s%n", time, input)
)
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I seem to get the idea, it's to combine two observable. But when I tried it, the console doesn't output any value. If I use observable like Observable.just("1"), then the console can output the value. But if use StringObservable.from(System.in), the value is not displayed. It seems like somehow the System.in has blocked the rest of the program.

Comment: I guess you need to `sleep` after `subscribe` or use `blockingSubscribe` to prevent Java from killing the flow.